# Recursive folder synchronization using VBScript (Mirror Folders)

Tags: vbscript, copy, synchronization, mirror

I've never really written in vbs (once wrote a script that would welcome me on boot) but I'm after a script to essentially perform :

```
robocopy "folder1" "folder2" /MIR
```

At the moment what I've got is a copied script from here [VBS Mirror](http://www.808.dk/?code-foldersync), Using the top script :

> This code synchronizes the contents (files and subfolders) of two
>   folders. Each folder is traversed recursively and any missing
>   subfolders and files are copied both ways. If corresponding folders
>   contain files with matching file names but with different time stamps,
>   the file with the newest time stamp will overwrite the older.

***SyncFolders.vbs***

```
Option Explicit
ForceScriptEngine("cscript")

Dim wshArgs
Set wshArgs = Wscript.Arguments
If WshArgs.Count = 2 Then
  Call SyncFolders(WshArgs.Item(0), WshArgs.Item(1))
  ' Also run once in reverse to catch mismatching subfolder count:
  Call SyncFolders(WshArgs.Item(1), WshArgs.Item(0))
Else
  Wscript.Echo("Wrong number of arguments. Syntax: SyncFolders Folder1 Folder2")
  Wscript.Sleep(3000) ' To allow Function syntax popup message to be seen.
End If

Sub SyncFolders(strFolder1, strFolder2)
  Dim objFileSys
  Dim objFolder1
  Dim objFolder2
  Dim objFile1
  Dim objFile2
  Dim objSubFolder
  Dim arrFolders
  Dim i
  Set objFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  arrFolders = Array(strFolder1, strFolder2)
  For i = 0 To 1 ' Make sure that missing folders are created first:
    If objFileSys.FolderExists(arrFolders(i)) = False Then
      wscript.echo("Creating folder " & arrFolders(i))
      objFileSys.CreateFolder(arrFolders(i))
    End If
  Next
  Set objFolder1 = objFileSys.GetFolder(strFolder1)
  Set objFolder2 = objFileSys.GetFolder(strFolder2)
  For i = 0 To 1
    If i = 1 Then ' Reverse direction of file compare in second run
      Set objFolder1 = objFileSys.GetFolder(strFolder2)
      Set objFolder2 = objFileSys.GetFolder(strFolder1)
    End If
    For Each objFile1 in objFolder1.files
      If Not objFileSys.FileExists(objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name) Then
        Wscript.Echo("Copying " & objFolder1 & "\" & objFile1.name & _
          " to " & objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name)
        objFileSys.CopyFile objFolder1 & "\" & objFile1.name, _
          objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name
      Else
        Set objFile2 = objFileSys.GetFile(objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name)
        If objFile1.DateLastModified > objFile2.DateLastModified Then
          Wscript.Echo("Overwriting " & objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name & _
            " with " & objFolder1 & "\" & objFile1.name)
          objFileSys.CopyFile objFolder1 & "\" & objFile1.name, _
            objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name    
        End If
      End If
    Next
  Next
  For Each objSubFolder in objFolder1.subFolders
    Call SyncFolders(strFolder1 & "\" & objSubFolder.name, strFolder2 & _
      "\" & objSubFolder.name)
  Next
  Set objFileSys = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ForceScriptEngine(strScriptEng)
  ' Forces this script to be run under the desired scripting host.
  ' Valid arguments are "wscript" or "cscript".
  ' The command line arguments are passed on to the new call.
  Dim arrArgs
  Dim strArgs
  For Each arrArgs In WScript.Arguments
    strArgs = strArgs & " " & Chr(34) & arrArgs & Chr(34)
  Next
  If Lcase(Right(Wscript.FullName, 12)) = "\wscript.exe" Then
    If Instr(1, Wscript.FullName, strScriptEng, 1) = 0 Then
      CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "cscript.exe //Nologo " & _
        Chr(34) & Wscript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & strArgs
      Wscript.Quit
    End If
  Else
    If Instr(1, Wscript.FullName, strScriptEng, 1) = 0 Then
      CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "wscript.exe " & Chr(34) & _
        Wscript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & strArgs
      Wscript.Quit
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

I changed the :

```
Sub SyncFolders(strFolder1, strFolder2)
```

to

```
Sub SyncFolders(strC:\Users\Zac\Desktop\Folder, strW:\Folder)
```

and get the error "Expected ')'

I'm sure it's something very obvious, but could someone please tell me what I need to change in that script to make my folders mirror each other?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not overly sure what I'm supposed to do here. I have changed the "strFolder1" and "strFolder2" to my directories in almost every combination I can think of, but still get an error of some sort? Which ones do I need to change in order for it to work?

Comment: You should call the sub like this way ==>  Call SyncFolders("C:\Users\Zac\Desktop\Folder" ,"W:\Folder")

Comment: The issue here is you changed the `Sub SyncFolders(strFolder1, strFolder2)` definition to incorrect syntax. Personally you first need to learn how to write and structure VBScript before trying to use scripts like this. The script is self contained you just need to call it and pass the expected arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this vbscript force to deal with Cscript engine; you should execute it by a litlle batch like this way :

```
@echo off
Cscript /nologo SyncFolders.vbs "C:\Users\Zac\Desktop\Folder" "W:\Folder"
pause
```

***Edit :***
And if you like to avoid this batch and using Cscript engine,try this :

```
Option Explicit
'You must only change the absolute paths of the two folders here
Call SyncFolders("C:\Users\Zac\Desktop\Folder","W:\Folder") 
'**********************Don't Change nothing below this line *****************************
Sub SyncFolders(strFolder1, strFolder2)
  Dim objFileSys
  Dim objFolder1
  Dim objFolder2
  Dim objFile1
  Dim objFile2
  Dim objSubFolder
  Dim arrFolders
  Dim i
  Set objFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  arrFolders = Array(strFolder1, strFolder2)
  For i = 0 To 1 ' Make sure that missing folders are created first:
    If objFileSys.FolderExists(arrFolders(i)) = False Then
      'wscript.echo("Creating folder " & arrFolders(i))
      objFileSys.CreateFolder(arrFolders(i))
    End If
  Next
  Set objFolder1 = objFileSys.GetFolder(strFolder1)
  Set objFolder2 = objFileSys.GetFolder(strFolder2)
  For i = 0 To 1
    If i = 1 Then ' Reverse direction of file compare in second run
      Set objFolder1 = objFileSys.GetFolder(strFolder2)
      Set objFolder2 = objFileSys.GetFolder(strFolder1)
    End If
    For Each objFile1 in objFolder1.files
      If Not objFileSys.FileExists(objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name) Then
        'Wscript.Echo("Copying " & objFolder1 & "\" & objFile1.name & _
        '  " to " & objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name)
        objFileSys.CopyFile objFolder1 & "\" & objFile1.name, _
          objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name
      Else
        Set objFile2 = objFileSys.GetFile(objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name)
        If objFile1.DateLastModified > objFile2.DateLastModified Then
          'Wscript.Echo("Overwriting " & objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name & _
          '  " with " & objFolder1 & "\" & objFile1.name)
          objFileSys.CopyFile objFolder1 & "\" & objFile1.name, _
            objFolder2 & "\" & objFile1.name    
        End If
      End If
    Next
  Next
  For Each objSubFolder in objFolder1.subFolders
    Call SyncFolders(strFolder1 & "\" & objSubFolder.name, strFolder2 & _
      "\" & objSubFolder.name)
  Next
  Set objFileSys = Nothing
End Sub
'********************************************************************************
```

Comment: So I used a batch file, still getting an expected ')' error, I ran it without the batch file, got the same error, the error message is; 
Line:15
Char: 18
Error: Expected ')'

Comment: HAHA, it's working, thank you, just one more question, how do I stop the dialogue box coming up, I'm planning on having this autorun whenever "W:\" drive is connected, and don't want any interaction with it.

Comment: @ZacharyWight Which is why you use `cscript.exe` ;)

Comment: @ZacharyWight Just comments every line where you find wscript.echo; so check it now !

Comment: If you run with the `WScript.Echo` statements but call the script with `cscript.exe` they will output to the `StdOut` buffer no interaction required. No interaction and No Feedback are two different things.

Comment: Every time is ask a question and you answer, it's always exactly what I need, thank you. @Hackoo

Comment: @ZacharyWight Personally commenting out the `WScript.Echo` just means there is no feedback at all which in my experience is never a good thing. Plus looking at your question history it's clear what kind of a community member you are.

Comment: @ZacharyWight Your are welcome and don't forget to vote and mark the question as answered !

Comment: Good luck with that have you checked their previous questions?

Comment: This script will not create folders  (and copy files) for subfolders  which are present in the first folder but not present in the first folder. I had to run two calls to achieve this. `Call SyncFolders(A,B)` followed by `CallSyncFolders(B,A)`