# Can VBScript determine when a folder is done being written to?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a vbscript that can detect when a file has finished being written to. Basically the scenario is this;

We have two drives for the company I work for, an offsite and onsite. Every morning we push a build to the onsite drive, and then once its finished manually push it to offsite from onsite.

I'd like to know if its possible to detect when the folder is finished being written to, and then automatically copy it over to the new location. I've got a script that will copy builds over, so that's not the important part, but I'd like some advice on the best way to detect when the folder is finished being copied over.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When it's finished you'll be able to open it. Wait till you can successfully open it.

Comment: Can't folders be open while they are being copied?

Comment: The question was for a file not a folder. _I'm trying to create a vbscript that can detect when a file has finished being written to_

Comment: My apologies I miss typed the question, I'd like to copy over a folder that has multiple files in it. But I need to determine if the folder and all subfolders/subfiles are finished before copying. Any ideas?

Comment: Well that should be easy, I think, you only need to know when the *build script* is done, right?

Comment: You can take a look at this vbscript ==> [Recursive folder synchronization using VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449614/recursive-folder-synchronization-using-vbscript-mirror-folders?answertab=active#tab-top)